# Keras Lambda layers gives ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer xxx: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

When I add lambda layer to my sequential model it gives ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with ....

For this model I get `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer flatten_1: expected min_ndim=3, found ndim=2`

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen))
model1.add(Lambda(lambda x: mean(x, axis=1)))
model1.add(Flatten())
model1.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32)))
model1.add(Dropout(0.6))
model1.add(Dense(2))
```

If I remove the `Flatten()` I get : `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer bidirectional_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2`. However, without lambda layer the model works fine.

Any idea on What is causing this problem and how can I solve this will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The output of your `Lambda` layer is already flattened, so there's no need for a `Flatten` here.

Comment: @AlexisI tried to reshape the model with model1.add(Reshape((100,200))) but get ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following generates a graph that seems correct:

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import *
import numpy as np

max_words = 1000
embedding_dim = 300
maxlen = 10

def mean(x, axis):
  """mean
     input_shape=(batch_size, time_slots, ndims)
     depending on the axis mean will:
       0: compute mean value for a batch and reduce batch size to 1
       1: compute mean value across time slots and reduce time_slots to 1
       2: compute mean value across ndims an reduce dims to 1.
  """
  return K.mean(x, axis=axis, keepdims=True)

model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(Embedding(max_words, embedding_dim, input_length=maxlen))
model1.add(Lambda(lambda x: mean(x, axis=1)))
model1.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(32)))
model1.add(Dropout(0.6))
model1.add(Dense(2))
model1.compile('sgd', 'mse')
model1.summary()
```

The Embedding layer uses 3 dimensions (batch_size, maxlen, embedding_dim).
The LSTM layer is also expecting 3 dimensions. So the lambda should return a shape that is compatible or you need to reshape. Here K.mean offers a convenient param (keepdims) which help us do that.

Comment: Can you please explain why that works? You have one dummy function which simply returns x. Of course that is not what mean is supposed to do but why does this work?

Comment: Edited the answer to add a mean across time_slots.